# Make text input Georgian instead of English

Tags: reactjs

I need to write Georgian text in react input. for example, if user writes `abc` it should be `აბც`(Keys that are one Georgian keyboard instead of a,b and c).

I tried using plugins like `react-language-keyboard` but its too old and throwing error, (You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM))

Comment: If you are asking for library recommendations, I'm afraid that is off-topic for this site. If not, please clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @DBS is there a way to change input value on change? or get charcodes/letters of all symbols in input and change it to another.